# Neo4j In memory configurations, multithreading, and slow writes

Tags: neo4j

How do I improve performance when writing to neo4j. I currently have neo4j set up on a server and I am currently running it in embedded more. I believe my configurations are storing all the content of my graph database in memory based upon configurations I've found online

```
neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=0 
neostore.relationship.db.mapped_memory=0
neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=0
neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory=0
neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory=0
neostore.propertystore.db.index.keys.mapped_memory=0
neostore.propertystore.db.index.mapped_memory=0

node_auto_indexing=true

node_keys_indexable=type,id

cache_type=strong
use_memory_mapped_buffers=false
node_cache_size=12G
relationship_cache_size=12G
node_cache_array_fraction=10
relationship_cache_array_fraction=10
```

Please let me know if this is incorrect. The problem that I am encountering is that when I try to persist information to the graph database. It appears that those times are not very quick in comparison to our MYSQL times of the samething(ex. to add 250 items would take about 3sec and in MYSQL it takes 1sec) .   I read online that when you have multiple indexes that that can slow down performance on persisting data so I am working on that right now to see if that is my culprit. But, I just wanted to make sure that my configurations seem to be inline when it comes to running your graph database in memory.

Second question to this topic.  Okay, if my configurations are good and my database is indeed in memory, then is there a way to optimize persisting data just in case this isn't the silver bullet. If we ran one thread against our test that executes this functionality, oppose to 10 threads, its seems like the times for execution bubbles up
ex.( thread 1 finishes 1s, thread 2 finishes 2s, thread 3 finishes 3s,etc). Is there some special multithreaded configuration that I am missing to improve the performance when mulitple threads are hitting it at one time.

```
Neo4J version
1.9.1-enterprise

My Jvm configs are 
-Xms25G -Xmx25G -XX:+UseNUMA -XX:+UseSerialGC

My Machine Specs:
File system type ext3
```

Answer (score 0):

You cache arguments are invalid.

```
node_cache_size=12G
relationship_cache_size=12G
node_cache_array_fraction=10
relationship_cache_array_fraction=10
```

These can only be used with the `GCR` cache. Setting the cache isn't going to put everything in memory for you at start up, you will have to write code to do this for you. Something like this:

```
GlobalGraphOperations ggo = GlobalGraphOperations.at(graphDatabaseFactory);
for (Node n : ggo.getAllNodes()) {
    for (String propertyKey : n.getPropertyKeys()) {
        n.getProperty(propertyKey);
    }
    for (Relationship relationship : n.getRelationships()) {
    }
}
```

Beware with the strong cache, if you have a lot of nodes/relationships, eventually your cache will become large and performing GC against it will cause long pauses in your system.

My recommendation would be to use the memory mapped files, as this is an OS handled and will be outside of heap space. It doesn't provide near the speed of caching, but it will provide a speed up if you have to read from the neo store.